# Unir dos tablas en un mismo query

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos *queries* que me arrojan resultados agrupando fechas:

**Query 1:**

```sql
Select fecha, count(order_id) as ordenes
From orders
```

**Query 2:**

```sql
Select fecha, count(chat_id) as chats
From chat
```

Quiero que al final me quede una tabla como:

```
fecha | ordenes | chats
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo? Intento con un join de fecha pero no me traer los resultados esperados porque las dos tablas tienen el detalle de **orden por orden** y **chat por chat.**

```sql
SELECT date(o.registered_date) as fecha,
    count(DISTINCT o.order_id) as total_orders, 
    sum(case when o.fail_rate_owner = 'Confirmed' then 1 else 0 end) as confirmed_orders, 
    sum(case when o.fail_rate_owner != 'Confirmed' then 1 else 0 end) as rejected_orders,
    sum(case when o.fail_rate_owner = 'Restaurant' then 1 else 0 end) as rejected_by_restaurant,
    sum(logistic_orders.vendor_late)/60 as vendor_late_total_min,v 
    sum(case when logistic_orders.vendor_late>=600 then 1 else 0 end) as ordenes_vendor_late_total,
    sum(case when logistic_orders.is_preorder=false then logistic_orders.actual_delivery_time else null end)/60 as delivery_time_total
    from orders as o
    LEFT JOIN logistic_orders on o.order_id=logistic_orders.platform_order_code
    where o.country_id=6 and o.yyyymm>='202012' 
GROUP BY date(o.registered_date)
ORDER BY date(o.registered_date) ASC
```

---

```sql
select date_id, 
    sum( case when chat_button IN ('CS_SPA_ClickDelivery_Customer_Level_1','CS_SPA_ClickDelivery_Customer_Level_1_VD') then 
    1 else 0 end) as chats_cs_recibidos,
    sum( case when chat_status='Completed' and chat_button IN ('CS_SPA_ClickDelivery_Customer_Level_1','CS_SPA_ClickDelivery_Customer_Level_1_VD') then 
    1 else 0 end) as chats_cs_atendidos,
    sum( case when chat_button IN ('CS_SPA_ClickDelivery_Customer_Level_1','CS_SPA_ClickDelivery_Customer_Level_1_VD') then 
    missed_chats else 0 end) as chats_cs_perdidos
    from gcc_salesforce_chats
    where country_id=6 and yyyymm>='202012'
group by date_id
order by date_id ASC
```

Comment: puedes poner el código que llevas hasta ahora!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! probaste con un join?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es un `join` entre las dos consultas para unirlas por la fecha, probablemente la mejor opción sería con un `left join` de manera que aparezcan todas las ordenes.

Ten en cuenta que aparecerán todas las fechas de las ordenes. Si hay chats en en otras fechas distintas y quieres mostrarlos, la consulta no te los mostrará.

```
SELECT a.fecha, ordenes, chats
FROM (
   Select fecha, count(order_id) as ordenes
   From orders
) a 
left join (
   Select fecha, count(chat_id) as chats
   From chat
) b on a.fecha = b.fecha
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! :) me funciono

Comment: Es probable que se requiera un full join para asegurar que no se pierdan datos de la tabla chat.